# How to make an infinite autoscrolling loop of my images in React (im using MUI in my front end)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, scroll

I want to create an infinite loop that will auto scroll from top to bottom my images that are inside my Box element(im using MUI for styling).

```
<Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box
            ref={animatedImgRef}
            className={`animated-box movingImgs ${
              isAnimatedImg ? "animate" : ""
            } `}
            sx={{
              borderRadius: 40,
              width: 500,
              height: 450,
              overflowY: "scroll",
              marginY: 70,
            }}
          >
            <ImageList variant="masonry" cols={3} gap={8}>
              {itemData.map((item) => (
                <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
                  <img
                    src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
                    srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
                    alt={item.title}
                    loading="lazy"
                  />
                  <ImageListItemBar position="below" title={item.author} />
                </ImageListItem>
              ))}
            </ImageList>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
```

this is the entire code of my JSX file:

```
import { Box, Container, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState, createRef, useRef } from "react";
import CheckAuth from "../components/checkAuth";
import AirplanemodeActiveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AirplanemodeActive";
import ImageList from "@mui/material/ImageList";
import ImageListItem from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";
import ImageListItemBar from "@mui/material/ImageListItemBar";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function Home() {
  const [isAnimated, setIsAnimated] = useState(false);
  const [isAnimatedImg, setIsAnimatedImg] = useState(false);

  const animatedRef = useRef(null);
  const animatedImgRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const box1Position = animatedRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const box2Position = animatedImgRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const offset = viewportHeight / 2;

    setIsAnimated(box1Position.top <= offset);
    setIsAnimatedImg(box2Position.top <= offset);
  };

**The images are hard coded here for now**

  const itemData = [
    {
      img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549388604-817d15aa0110",
      title: "Bed",
      author: "swabdesign",
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <CheckAuth>
      <Grid className="dark waves" container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ margin: 20, color: "white" }}>
          <Box
            className="welcome"
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Typography
              sx={{
                alignItems: "flex-start",
                paddingY: 4,
              }}
              variant="h3"
              component="h1"
            >
              Your Journey Starts Here...
              <AirplanemodeActiveIcon
                fontSize="large"
                className="animated-plane"
              />
            </Typography>
            <Box>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non vero
              incidunt maiores alias doloribus! Eos totam repudiandae fuga?
              Aliquid voluptas magni blanditiis quia commodi recusandae ullam
              voluptatum iure maiores consectetur.
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        className="white waves"
        sx={{ flexDirection: "row-reverse" }}
        container
        spacing={2}
      >
        <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ margin: 20 }}>
          <Box
            ref={animatedRef}
            className={`animated-box ${isAnimated ? "animate" : ""}`}
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
            }}
          >
            <Typography
              sx={{ alignItems: "flex-start", paddingY: 4 }}
              variant="h3"
              component="h1"
            >
              ZipTrip: Unveil the World, One Journey at a Time
            </Typography>

            <Box>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo
              deserunt impedit cum maiores, sit laboriosam quo, perferendis
              officia nihil consectetur nesciunt quae esse, ipsa mollitia
              aperiam dolor quaerat autem nulla! Aperiam error ea, soluta animi
              neque dolore, eveniet ipsam dolorem nihil ab, dolorum tenetur in
              perspiciatis alias placeat fugit cum id dignissimos provident
              minus nobis dolor necessitatibus reprehenderit commodi. Ipsam! Nam
              impedit illo atque, molestiae at tempora quaerat laboriosam velit
              esse! Eius porro optio ea magnam cupiditate. Recusandae fugit aut
              corrupti magnam nulla magni tenetur corporis nostrum. Accusamus,
              impedit autem. Accusamus explicabo hic molestiae a, dignissimos
              ipsam ratione dolorem aut ducimus impedit veritatis facere
              mollitia soluta reiciendis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
              adipisicing elit. Non vero incidunt maiores alias doloribus! Eos
              totam repudiandae fuga? Aliquid voluptas magni blanditiis quia
              commodi recusandae ullam voluptatum iure maiores consectetur.Lorem
              ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <div className="wave">
            <svg
              data-name="Layer 1"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
              preserveAspectRatio="none"
            >
              <path
                d="M985.66,92.83C906.67,72,823.78,31,743.84,14.19c-82.26-17.34-168.06-16.33-250.45.39-57.84,11.73-114,31.07-172,41.86A600.21,600.21,0,0,1,0,27.35V120H1200V95.8C1132.19,118.92,1055.71,111.31,985.66,92.83Z"
                className="shape-fill"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box
            ref={animatedImgRef}
            className={`animated-box movingImgs ${
              isAnimatedImg ? "animate" : ""
            } `}
            sx={{
              borderRadius: 40,
              width: 500,
              height: 450,
              overflowY: "scroll",
              marginY: 70,
            }}
          >
            <ImageList variant="masonry" cols={3} gap={8}>
              {itemData.map((item) => (
                <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
                  <img
                    src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
                    srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
                    alt={item.title}
                    loading="lazy"
                  />
                  <ImageListItemBar position="below" title={item.author} />
                </ImageListItem>
              ))}
            </ImageList>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </CheckAuth>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).